# Yowsup-cli Old Version failed registration

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

i am trying to register my number with yowsup-cli (yowsup-cli registration --requestcode voice --phone 49************* --config-cc 49 --config-mcc 262 --config-mnc 01), but i get this error

```
yowsup.common.http.warequest - b'{"login":"49***********", "status":"fail", "reason":"old_version"}'\n
status: b'fail'
reason: b'old_version'
login: b'49**********'
```

I am using the newest yowsup version and yowsup-cli
So:
yowsup-cli v3.2.0
yowsup v3.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Check the env_android.py file located  .../yowsup/env 
Right settings for current version:

_VERSION = = "2.21.12.22" 
_MD5_CLASSES = "5ym5gLRrSZJQ+ZWWrpHaMg=="

Reinstall yowsup after editing file.